# Why docker not syncing files inside container on Windows 10?

Tags: php, windows, docker, nginx, phpstorm

I have issue after last docker update (seems so) on Windows 10 (local development). When I changed files in PhpStorm (and in another editors - Sublime, Notepad+), after a while, files inside container didn't receive changes.

Steps that can help for a while:

- If I completely shut down all containers and after that arise them again. `docker-compose down && docker-compoes up`
- If I get into php-fpm container and for file that not changed ran  `touch file.php` (this file will be immidiatly changed).

What I tried and it didn't help:

- I restarted php-fpm and nginx containers  `docker-compose restart php-fpm nginx` (Yes it's strange, because down|up for all container  helped)
- I changed inside PhpStorm setting *Use Safe write(save changes for temporary file first)*

Also I checked inode for file inside container. With `ls -lai file.php`. Before changes worked and after they broked I had the same inode number. There is no determined number of changes I must to do to break syncing, it's random, sometime 2 changes enough.

I have:

> Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
>
> docker-compose version 1.25.2, build 698e2846

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        container_name: pr_kpi-nginx
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/nginx.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/kpi
            - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./docker/nginx/fastcgi.conf:/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
        links:
            - php-fpm
        networks:
            - internal

    php-fpm:
        container_name: pr_kpi-php-fpm
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/php-fpm.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/kpi
        links:
            - kpi-mysql
        environment:
            # 192.168.221.1 -> host.docker.internal for Mac and Windows
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_enable=1"
            PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
        networks:
            - internal

    mailhog:
        container_name: pr_kpi-mailhog
        image: mailhog/mailhog
        restart: always
        ports:
            # smtp
            - "1025:1025"
            # http
            - "8025:8025"
        networks:
            - internal

    kpi-mysql:
        container_name: pr_kpi-kpi-mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        command: mysqld --sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
        volumes:
            - ./docker/storage/kpi-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            # We must change prod secrets, this is not good approach
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass"
            - "MYSQL_USER=user"
            - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_pass"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=kpi_db"
        ports:
            - "33061:3306"
        networks:
            - internal

    kpi-npm:
        container_name: pr_kpi-npm
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/npm.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/kpi
            - /var/www/kpi/admin/node_modules
        ports:
            - "4200:4200"
        networks:
            - internal
        tty: true


# For xdebug
networks:
    internal:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 192.168.221.0/28
```

P.S. There is opened issue:
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5530

P.P.S. We need to update Docker from 2.2.0.0 to 2.2.0.3, Seems it's fixed

Comment: please add your docker-compose.yml

Comment: @RiWe docker-compose was added

Comment: The docker-compose.yml looks good to me.

Comment: Having same issue. Wondering if a sleep on the host triggers it. touch sometimes fixes it. Restarting docker desktop did not resolve it.

Comment: Might be related to this one: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5530

Answer (score 1):

I have a separate container for syncing my folder:

```
app:
    image: httpd:2.4.38
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html
    command: "echo true"
```

I just use the basic apache image, you could use anything really though. Then in my actual containers, I use the following `volumes_from` key:

```
awesome.scot:
    build: ./build/httpd
    links:
        - php
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
    volumes_from:
        - app

php:
    build: ./build/php
    ports:
        - 9000
        - 9001
    volumes_from:
        - app
    links:
        - mariadb
        - mail
    environment:
        APPLICATION_ENV: 'development'
```

I've never had an issue using this set up, files always sync fast, and I have tested both on Mac OSX and MS Windows.

If you're interested, here is my full LAMP stack on Github https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Windows10 since 31st Jan.
I have commented a line in PhpStorm and checked it in the container using vim.
The changes were not there.
If I run docker-compose down and up, the changes go in the container.

Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a

Nothing changed in my docker-compose.yml since 2018.